# Is there a way to add a CSS class to a DOM element while dragging the cursor and mouse click pressed?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, dom-events

I'm trying to create a **pathfinder visualizer.** So far I have created a 16x45 grid with the following function:

```
export const drawBoard = () => {
  const boardContainer: HTMLDivElement | null = document.querySelector(
    ".board-container"
  );

  if (boardContainer != null) {
    // 16x45 board
    for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      const row = document.createElement("div");
      row.classList.add("row");
      for (let j = 0; j < 45; j++) {
        const col = document.createElement("col");
        col.classList.add("col");
        col.setAttribute("data-row", `${i}`);
        col.setAttribute("data-col", `${j}`);
        row.appendChild(col);
        col.addEventListener("click", function () {
             this.classList.add("wall"); // Add a wall class to the CSS
        });
      }
      boardContainer.appendChild(row);
    }
  }
};
```

This function generates the following grid in my document:

[image]

I can get the `x` and `y` position of a specific tile, as seen here:

[image]

I've added `click events` to all this tiles. So that **when I click** a tile a `wall` *CSS class* is added to that tile and fills it with black color.

**My question is the following:**

> Is there a way to add the CSS `wall` class to the tiles while the mouse is pressed? Is there a special event listener for this?

**This is what I want to achieve:**

[image]

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track whether or not the mouse is down, and listen for `mousemove`. Something like this should work:

```js
//stores whether or not the mouse is down
let mouseDown = false;
document.addEventListener("mousedown" () => mouseDown = true);
document.addEventListener("mouseup" () => mouseDown = false);

export const drawBoard = () => {
  const boardContainer: HTMLDivElement | null = document.querySelector(
    ".board-container"
  );

  if (boardContainer != null) {
    // 16x45 board
    for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      const row = document.createElement("div");
      row.classList.add("row");
      for (let j = 0; j < 45; j++) {
        const col = document.createElement("col");
        col.classList.add("col");
        col.setAttribute("data-row", `${i}`);
        col.setAttribute("data-col", `${j}`);
        row.appendChild(col);
        
        //added mousemove listener
        col.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
          //if mouse is down add class
          mouseDown && this.classList.add("wall")
        });
        col.addEventListener("click", function() {
          //do not need to check for mousedown
          this.classList.add("wall")
        });
      }
      boardContainer.appendChild(row);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mousedown event to achieve what you're looking for. There's also a corresponding mouseup event as well.

Here's a reference of all events as well.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events